# Asymptotics of $\Gamma(z+\alpha)/\Gamma(z+\beta)$ when all three parameters $\to \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

Lots of results are known about the asymptotic ratio of two gamma functions when $z\to\infty$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are constants, the most basic one being:

$$\frac{\Gamma(z+\alpha)}{\Gamma(z+\beta)} \sim z^{\alpha - \beta}$$

What about the case where $\alpha,\beta \to \infty$ as well? Experimenting a bit, everything seems to work as expected provided that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $o(z)$, but the asymptotic is wrong if one is $O(z)$ and the other is not. Are there other regimes I need to worry about? Pointers to the literature would be appreciated.

Comment: (For a particular scaling, I can use Stirling's approximation to get the correct limit, but how many possible scalings are there?)

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln (\Gamma(t)) = t \ln(t) - t - \frac{\ln(t)}{2} + \frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2} + o(1)\ \text{as}\ t \to \infty$$
so if $z, \alpha, \beta$ are all reals with $z+\alpha$ and $z+\beta$ going to $+\infty$
$$ \ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(z+\alpha)}{\Gamma(z+\beta)}\right) = (z+\alpha)\ln(z+\alpha) - (z+\beta)\ln(z+\beta)
 - \alpha + \beta - \frac{\ln(z+\alpha)}{2} + \frac{\ln(z+\beta)}{2} + o(1)$$
Which of those terms are larger and which are smaller will depend on the relationships between $z, \alpha, \beta$.